# Python IndexError: image index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, error-handling

I wrote a program to generate the image pixel RGB.

but it's returning an error:

```
g = pix[x,x][1]
IndexError: image index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import with_statement
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('i100m0729.jpg') #relative path to file

#load the pixel info
pix = im.load()

#get a tuple of the x and y dimensions of the image
width, height = im.size

#open a file to write the pixel data
with open('distort_RGB.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('X,Y,R,G,B\n')

#read the details of each pixel and write them to the file
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r = pix[x,y][0]
        g = pix[x,x][1]
        b = pix[x,x][2]
        f.write('{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}\n'.format(x+1,y+1,r,g,b))
```

Here is the image I am using: [i100m0729.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKLNy.jpg)

Comment: Could you add some `print` between each of the line where you assign the values to r,g and b, to know which one causes a problem

Comment: It's g has a bug.    g = pix[x,x][1]  ~ IndexError: image index out of range

Comment: Why do you use `x,x` instead of `x,y` as indexes ?